# How to maximize function by picking rows to "median" in data frame in R?

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, median

I have a number of columns in a data frame in R that are binary - all entries are either 0 or 1.  I have a function that takes the median value of each row of a data frame then runs that "median" number (also a 0 or 1) through a function and returns a value.

How I could write a function that would go through these columns and find the optimum column choices to maximize the function?

Comment: Be aware that `median(0:1)` returns `0.5` - an integer result isn't guaranteed. Also, something like `as.numeric(colSums(x) > nrow(x)/2)` might be more efficient for calculating the median.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - but I wanna know if they are evenly split.